# Share Cookie authentication between ASP.NET Core 2.2 and ASP. NET MVC 5 (.NET Framework 4.6.1) without Microsoft.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-core

I have two application, the old one written in ASP.NET MVC5 and the new one written in ASP.NET Core 2.2. I want to share the cookie created in the ASP.NET Core application to the ASP.NET MVC5.
I tried what is explained in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-2.2 but seems that my ASP.NET MVC5 doesn’t find the cookie. (Maybe because I’m not using Microsoft.Identity for the users?)
The cookie is created in ASP.NET Core with this configuration (Startup.cs):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      // Cookie
      services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
      {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
      }); 



services.AddDataProtection()
      .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"))
      .SetApplicationName(CookieConst.SHARED_APP_NAME);

  services
    .AddAuthentication(CookieConst.AUTHENTICATION_TYPE)
    .AddCookie(CookieConst.AUTHENTICATION_TYPE, options =>
    {
      options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
      options.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
      options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/login");
      options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/login");
      options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
      options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
      options.Cookie.Name = CookieConst.AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME;
      options.Cookie.Path = "/";
      options.Cookie.Domain = "localhost";
      options.DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(
        new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"),
        (builder) => { builder.SetApplicationName(CookieConst.SHARED_APP_NAME); }).CreateProtector(
                  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
                  CookieConst.AUTHENTICATION_TYPE,
                  "v2");
    });

   …

}
```

The cookie is created with this code called by login:

```
public void Validate()
{
  AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties;
  ClaimsPrincipal principal;
  string cultureName;

  var expireTime = DateTimeHelper.GetNowDate().AddMinutes(CookieConst.EXPIRE_TIME_IN_MINUTES);

  authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties()
  {
    AllowRefresh = true,
    IsPersistent = true,
    ExpiresUtc = expireTime
  };

  // Add Authentication Cookie
  var claims = new List<Claim>
      {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "test"),
        new Claim(BeanClaimTypes.User, "-1"),
        new Claim(BeanClaimTypes.Company, "-1"),
        new Claim(BeanClaimTypes.Roles, "testRole"),
        new Claim(BeanClaimTypes.Permissions, "testPermission"),
        new Claim(BeanClaimTypes.Culture, "en-US")
      };
  var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieConst.AUTHENTICATION_TYPE);
  principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

  HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieConst.AUTHENTICATION_TYPE, principal, authenticationProperties);
}
```

In the ASP.NET MVC5 application this is the configuration (Startup.Auth.cs):

```
  public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
      //// Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
      //app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
      //app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
      //app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);  

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
      AuthenticationType = CookieConst.AUTHENTICATION_TYPE,
      CookieName = CookieConst.AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME,
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
      Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
      {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                      validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                      regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) =>
                          user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
      },
      TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(
          new DataProtectorShim(
              DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"),
                  (builder) => { builder.SetApplicationName(CookieConst.SHARED_APP_NAME); })
              .CreateProtector(
                  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
                  CookieConst.AUTHENTICATION_TYPE,
                  "v2"))),
    CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager()
  });

  app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

  System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name";
}
```

I don't understand the commented part and Provider property of CookieAuthenticationOptions, because I’m not using Microsoft.Identity and I don’t know how to read the cookie and “parse” it to have the ASP.NET MVC5 principal filled.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  options.Cookie.Domain = "localhost";
```

delete this this
for local host